# How to get latest updated parse object in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I don't know about parse and I want to learn it.I want to know how can I get the latest updated parse object in parse.I tried to use get first in background but I think there is a problem in my ParseQuery.Please provide me the right way of query to get the latest object I just pushed on the parse cloud back.

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("RBSE");
       query.whereEqualTo("roomA","900");

    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
        public void done(ParseObject objectLatest, ParseException e) {
        if(e==null){

        }
        else{


        }

        }
   }
```

Comment: you need to keep a last check date then use that in your query to find anything that was updated since the last time you checked

Comment: Please I dont know how to do that.Can you show me any example?which will work fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the most recently created/modified, simply sort descending by the "updatedAt" field (it is built-in).

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RBSE");
query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("RBSE", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      // got the most recently modified object... do something with it here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How to get the object every time they are pushed onto the parse cloud automatically as soon as possible.

Comment: That would require push notification. There's plenty of documentation about that on the Parse website: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android